# Conditional computing on pandas dataframe with an if statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
A     B    C
100   2    3
-100  2    3
```

I want a new column that multiplies either column B or C by the value of column A:

```
if A<0:
D = A*B

if A>=0:
D = A*C
```

So in the end I get:

```
A     B    C   D
100   2    3   200
-100  2    3   -300
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run a lambda function based on what you are looking like this:

```
df["D"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["A"] * row["B"] if row["A"] < 0 else row["A"] * row["C"], axis=1)
```